# Moment js default timezone not working when creating date

Tags: javascript, angular, timezone, momentjs

Please refer to the following code snippets.

**Problem 1:** I am setting default timezone for moment js. But right after setting it, If I retrieve the timezone from moment it is not what I just set.

```
console.log("Currrent timezone: "); console.log(moment.tz());
console.log("Updating timezone: "); console.log("America/Lima");
moment.tz.setDefault("America/Lima");
console.log("Currrent timezone after updating: "); console.log(moment.tz());
```

Following log is printed:

```
Currrent timezone: Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: true, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, _d: Wed Nov 15 2017 13:39:45 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time), …}
Updating timezone: America/Lima
Currrent timezone after updating: Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: true, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, _d: Wed Nov 15 2017 13:39:45 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time), …}
```

**Problem 2:** Also another problem is that, the default timezone which I set is applied to moment.format() function but not applied when creating new date objects from moment.

```
console.log(moment(new Date()).toDate()); // this uses user browser timezone
// prints Wed Nov 15 2017 13:57:40 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
// I want it to give the time in the timezone which i just set above

console.log(moment(new Date()).local().toDate());
// prints Wed Nov 15 2017 13:57:40 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)

console.log(moment(new Date()).format()); // this uses the timezone which I set above in moment default timezone. This is correct intended behavior
// prints: 2017-11-15T03:57:40-05:00
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**1. Solution:** Moment timezone setDefault is affecting the instances created after setDefault. If you debug like this:

```js
console.log("Currrent timezone: "); console.log(moment().tz());
console.log("Current time: "); console.log(moment().format());
console.log("Updating timezone: "); console.log("America/Lima");
moment.tz.setDefault("America/Lima");
console.log("Current time: "); console.log(moment().format());
console.log("Currrent timezone after updating: "); console.log(moment().tz());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.2/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.14/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can see the setDefault is working.

**2. Solution:** `.local()` function sets a flag on the original moment to use local time to display a moment instead of the original moment's time. Even if you use `moment.tz.setDefault` to alter the timezone, it gets the computer's timezone.

```js
console.log(moment(new Date()).format());
moment.tz.setDefault("America/Lima");
console.log(moment(new Date()).local().format());
console.log(moment(new Date()).format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.2/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.14/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In case it helps anyone: Make sure you're using the `moment-timezone-with-data.min.js` file, which you might miss if you're in a rush! (The `moment-timezone.js` one won't work for setting defaults because it lacks the data)